# How to stop/prevent Intellij from reverting maven-compiler-plugin target version

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have recently changed the **Java version from 14 to 15**.
And ever since, Intellij changed my **pom.xml** files on every startup.
It changes  version of  to 14.

Can someone help to prevent IntelliJ from editing my pom.xml files?

Answer (score 1):

So, the solution was very simple. 
I changed the SDK version in Intellij project settings to 15. 
**File -> Project Structure -> Project SDK** 
**File -> Project Structure -> Project language level**